# How to show maven build progress in cmd window

Tags: maven

We have a long build with maven. And I run it with cmd.  Is there a way to display percentage progress of the build in the cmd window title ?

Comment: I don't think Maven offers such a thing. But your build server might.

Comment: Ok, found this :   https://github.com/wokier/progress-maven-plugin

Comment: There is an output in the Maven output which shows how many modules are built...

Comment: With kh hint I did the following :

In a batch file run like this :

Start powershell "Get-content c:\test.txt -Tail 0 -Wait | where { $_ -match 'Building' }"

Cd project-directory
Call mvn install >>c:\test.txt


First line will start a powershell to detect progress in a text file.
Second line will output to a file.

Works nice !